# Recyclerview with a different last item as "add" item

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a layout with a list of items, where the last item is a button to add a new item of the "standard" type. It should be something like Google Keep lists, with a permanent "add" item at the end of the list.
[Google Keep list example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMov5.png)

I have tried two ways to achieve it. The first one is very simple, but I find a problem. The second one is not that simple, and the performance is worse. In addition, I think with the second way I am using `RecyclerView` in a way that is not intended, and I think I could find performance issues due to that.

How would you do it?

**First way**

The first one should be the easiest, that is adding in the same layout a `RecyclerView` followed by a `ViewGroup` containing the "add" item. As parent I use a `LinearLayout` with the `RecyclerView`  and an `Include` tag referenced to the "add" item layout. This is actually inside a `CoordinatorLayout` because I use a `BottomSheet` to pick the new "standard" item to be added.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundLight"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Other Views -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mainRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/itemAdd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the "add" item is positioned below the `RecyclerView`, and both disappear when the `RecyclerView` is empty.

**Second way**

Then I tried the second way, that is creating the "add" item from the `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Doing it this way is working so far, although I am sure that this cannot be the best way to do it. I will paste the code and below it I explain the reasoning behind.

*Adapter*

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;
    private int count = 0;
    private final List<Object> mDataset;

    // Standard constructor. I get the mInflater from Context here

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View itemView;
        if (count>=mDataset.size()) {
            itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_add, parent, false);
            itemView.setTag("ADD");
        }
        else{
            itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_sandard, parent, false);
            itemView.setTag(null);
        }
        count += 1;
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView, bottomSheetBehavior);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (position<mDataset.size()) {
            final Object object = mDataset.get(position);
            holder.bind(object); // I bind it on the ViewHolder
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size()+1;
    }
}
```

To do so I have created a private variable *mCount* that I use to count the amount of `ViewHolder` created. Then I start my `onCreateViewHolder` method with an *if* statment, where I check if I have already created the `ViewHolder`for the last "standard" item of my *mDataset*. Depending on it I inflate the "standard" view or the "add" view. Then I would have to be updating *mCount* values each time the user adds or deletes an item (not implemented yet). I also add a tag to the view to get which `View` I am using at the `ViewHolder` without big troubles.

I have to change the `onBindViewHolder` because in case I am inflating the "add" view, I don't want to bind anything as the view is already defined.

I also have to modify the `getItemCount` method to return the size of my *mDataset* plus 1 for the "add" view.

Finally I have to be sending the `BottomSheetBehaviour` instance all the way to the `ViewHolder` through the `Adapter` to be able to open the `BottomSheet` with the `onClick` defined in the `ViewHolder`, which I don't think is very efficient.

*ViewHolder*

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private final TextView mText;
    private final ImageButton mButton;


    public MyViewHolder(View itemView, final BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior) {
        super(itemView);

        if (itemView.getTag() == "ADD"){
            mText = null;
            mButton = null;
            // I also set the OnClickListener to open the BottomSheet
        }
        else{
            // Set mText and an OnClickListener to the button. I use the Adapter here
        }
    }

    // The bind method goes here 
}
```

Here I get the tag from the `View`, and depending on it I set a different listener.

Comment: Method 2 is the right approach. However you should not use the "count" variable at all, the "Add" view will always be at position "mDataSet.size()". What you need to do, when the user inserts or removes an entry, is to update your data set and then notify your adapter that the dataset was updated, preferably using notifyItemChanged instead of notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: I have tried to avoid the "count" variable, but I don't find the way to do it. I need to know the position where the `ViewHolder` will be placed at the beginning of `onCreateViewHolder`, because depending on it I would send one view or another. Could you help me with this step?

Comment: I used your second approach an didn't notice any slow down in the performance. Also I couldn't remove count

Answer (score 2):

I might be late here but try out this way if you have not found any solution..!!

```
    class AddMorePhotosAdapter(
    val context: Context,
    private val addImageListener: () -> Unit
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private val imageList = ArrayList<Bitmap>()
    fun addAll(list: ArrayList<Bitmap>) {
        imageList.clear()
        imageList.addAll(list)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class MyItemHolder(val binding: ItemSelectedPhotoBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(path: Bitmap, position: Int) {
            Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .load(path)
                .into(object : SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    override fun onResourceReady(
                        resource: Bitmap,
                        transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                    ) {
                        binding.tvSelectedImage.apply {
                            setImageBitmap(resource)
                            scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY
                        }
                    }
                })
        }
    }

    inner class MyFooterHolder(val binding: LayoutMultiplePhotoBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind() {
            binding.tvAddImage.setOnClickListener {
                addImageListener.invoke()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val binding: ViewBinding
        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            binding =
                ItemSelectedPhotoBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false)
            return MyItemHolder(binding)
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_FOOTER) {
            binding =
                LayoutMultiplePhotoBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false)
            return MyFooterHolder(binding)
        }
        throw RuntimeException("There is no type that matches the type $viewType. Make sure you are using view types correctly!")
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (getItemViewType(position)) {
            TYPE_ITEM -> (holder as MyItemHolder).bind(imageList[position], position)
            TYPE_FOOTER -> (holder as MyFooterHolder).bind()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = imageList.size + 1

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position == imageList.size) {
            TYPE_FOOTER
        } else {
            TYPE_ITEM
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TYPE_ITEM = 1
        private const val TYPE_FOOTER = 0
    }
}
```

-- I've used TYPE_TIME to show listing with recyclerview & TYPE_FOOTER to show "Add" image. both layout will be different to inflate.

check this image for refernece.[Initialy it will be only "Add" image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyMuP.png)