# View invisibility when RecyclerView is empty

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am using a `LinearLayout` with some views inside. The second last is a `RecyclerView`, and the last one is an `<include>` tag linked with a `RelativeLayout`. I want the last view to be visible permanently, as I want to use it to add items to the `RecyclerView`.

My problem is that the `<include>` view below the `RecyclerView` disappears whenever the adapter is empty. Is there any way to avoid this behaviour?

**EDIT**

There is a constraint in the way I want the `RecyclerView` and the "add" `View` to work together. I would like that it feels as the "add" view is always the last item in the `RecyclerView`, as it happens in Google Keep lists.

*Example* [Google Keep list example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfRY9.png) (I cannot add images yet)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace your LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout; then you anchor the bottom view to the bottom of the screen, and the RecyclerView would be set above that view. Something like this (just a skeleton):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent>

    <-! other views here -->

    <include layout="@layout/something"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@bottomView" />

    <RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/some_view_above_recyclerview"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: With this solution I would have the ´<include>´ visible, that's right. The problem is that I have another constraint that I didn't describe on my question for simplifying too much. I will edit my answer stating it too.

Comment: In that case, you need to define 2 view types for your adapter, and the last entry would be of view type "footer", where you add your footer view. However, this footer would only be visible when you scroll the list to the bottom.

Comment: I have already done so, but I think this solution is not optimized as the complexity increases too much for an really small issue. I have another question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927007/recyclerview-with-a-different-last-item-as-add-item) on how to implement the changes in the adapter, in case you could have a look and help me there. Maybe the way I solved it is too messy and there is a simpler way.