# How to add a button at the end of a recycler view (kotlin)?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm gonna add a button at the end of my recycler view
and i don't know how to do it .
i will appreciate you if you teach me .

this is my main activity code :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var number: Int = 0
private lateinit var name: String

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val myRecyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
    val myViewModel = ViewModel()
    myRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    myViewModel.getUserData()




    myViewModel.myList.observe(this) {
     
        myRecyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter(it)
    }


}
```

and this is my adapter code :

```
class MyAdapter(private val myList: List<Player>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyHolder {
    val myLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val myView = myLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_for_rv, parent, false)
    return MyHolder(myView)

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = myList[position]
    holder.bind(item)


}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return myList.size
}
```

and my holder class :

```
class MyHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
private val playerNumber  = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvNumber)
private val playerName = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvName)

fun bind(item : Player){
    playerName.text=item.name
    playerNumber.text=item.number.toString()
}
```

Comment: create Cell(item) view. and add a button in the item. then bind your custom item in the view.

Comment: You can try adding the `recyclerview` in a parent `nested scrollview` and then place the `button` below the `recyclerview`

Comment: Follow Karthick comment... It's  to easy , otherwise you need to handle viewtype it's little bit tricky... Follow the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927007/recyclerview-with-a-different-last-item-as-add-item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will achieve this by adding the `RecyclerView` in a parent `NestedScrollView` and then place the `Button` below the `RecyclerView`.

So your code should look like this

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

NOTE

> Add `recyclerView.nestedScrollingEnabled = false` for scroll to work for sdk 21

Comment: that exactly what i wanted , well then how can i change width or height a button in scroll ? except marginleft and margin right ?

Comment: Didn't get your point @M.hosseinKarimi

Comment: i added a button after a recycleview in nestedScrollView and don't know how to change its width or height @Kartik

Answer (score 0):

add a new itemType is good selection。

```
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        const val ITEM_TYPE_CONTENT = 0
        const val ITEM_TYPE_BUTTON = 1
    }

    val dataList: List<String>? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_CONTENT) {
            // TODO return a content holder
        }else {
            // TODO return a button holder
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return (dataList?.size ?: 0) + 1
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position == itemCount - 1) {
            ITEM_TYPE_BUTTON
        } else {
            ITEM_TYPE_CONTENT
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
package com.joon.fm.core.base.genericRecycler


import android.content.Context
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import android.util.SparseArray
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.util.set
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.joon.fm.core.extensions.getClass
import com.joon.fm.features.explore.section.SectionExploreNewReleases
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger


interface GenericAdapterView<Model> {
    fun onBind(model: Model, position: Int, extraObject: Any?)
}

data class Section<Model>(
    var type: Int,
    var data: Model,
    var extraObject: Any?,
    var index: Int = -1
)

open class VH(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)

interface DiffUtilModel {
    fun areItemsTheSame(o: DiffUtilModel): Boolean
    fun areContentsTheSame(o: DiffUtilModel): Boolean
}

class MyDiffCallback(private val oldList: List<Any?>, private val newList: List<Any?>) :
    DiffUtil.Callback() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        val old = oldList[oldItemPosition]
        val new = newList[newItemPosition]
        if (old is DiffUtilModel && new is DiffUtilModel) {
            return old.areItemsTheSame(new)
        }
        return oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition]
    }

    override fun getOldListSize() = oldList.size

    override fun getNewListSize() = newList.size

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        val old = oldList[oldItemPosition]
        val new = newList[newItemPosition]
        if (old is DiffUtilModel && new is DiffUtilModel) {
            return old.areContentsTheSame(new)
        }
        return (old == null && new == null) || (old != null && old == new)
    }

}

@Suppress("unused")
open class AppGenericAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    val sections = ArrayList<Section<*>>()
    var providers = SparseArray<(ViewGroup, Int) -> View>()

    private var types = HashMap<Class<*>, Pair<Int, Constructor<*>?>>()
    private var typeIds = AtomicInteger(0)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return VH(providers[viewType](parent, viewType))
    }


    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val v = holder.itemView as? GenericAdapterView<Any>
        val sec = sections[position]
        sec.data?.run {
            v?.onBind(this, position, sec.extraObject)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = sections.size
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = sections[position].type


    inline fun <reified V : View> viewType(addDefaultProvider: Boolean = true) =
        viewType(V::class.java, addDefaultProvider)

    fun viewType(cls: Class<*>, addDefaultProvider: Boolean = true): Int {
        val prevAns = types[cls]
        if (prevAns == null) {
            var cons: Constructor<*>? = null
            try {
                cons = cls.getDeclaredConstructor(Context::class.java)
            } catch (ignored: Throwable) {
            }
            types[cls] = Pair(typeIds.getAndIncrement(), cons)

            val type = types[cls]!!

            if (addDefaultProvider && providers[type.first] == null) {
                providers[type.first] = { vg, _ ->
                    type.second!!.newInstance(vg.context) as View
                }

            }
            return type.first
        } else {
            return prevAns.first
        }
    }


    inline fun <reified V> setProvider(noinline provider: (ViewGroup, Int) -> V) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<*> {
        providers[viewType<V>(false)] = provider
    }

    inline fun <reified V> provider(noinline provider: (Context) -> V) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<*> {
        providers[viewType<V>(false)] = { vg, _ -> provider(vg.context) }
    }

    inline fun <reified V> addProvider(noinline provider: (Context) -> V) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<*> {
        providers.set(viewType<V>(false)) { vg, _ -> provider(vg.context) }
    }


    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any> setSections(
        data: Collection<Model>,
        extra: Any? = null
    ) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> {
        sections.clear()
        addSections<V, Model>(data, extra)
    }

    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any> setSectionsDiffUtil(
        data: Collection<Model>,
        extra: Any? = null
    ) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> {

        val diffCallback = MyDiffCallback(sections.map { it.data }, data.toList())
        val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback)
        sections.clear()
        addSections<V, Model>(data, extra)
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)

    }

    fun setSectionsDiffUtil(newSections: Collection<Section<*>>) {
        val diffCallback = MyDiffCallback(sections.map { it.data }, newSections.map { it.data })
        val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback)
        sections.clear()
        sections.addAll(newSections)
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any> setSectionsAndNotify(
        data: Collection<Model>,
        extra: Any? = null
    ) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> {
        setSections<V, Model>(data, extra)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    fun  removeItemFromSectionsAndNotify(
        index: Int,
    ) {
        sections.removeAt(index)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any> setSectionsAndNotifyRange(
        data: Collection<Model>,
        extra: Any? = null
    ) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> {
        val prevSize = itemCount
        setSections<V, Model>(data, extra)
        val newSize = itemCount
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, newSize)
        if (prevSize > newSize) {
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(newSize, prevSize - newSize)
        }
    }


    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any> addSections(
        data: Collection<Model>,
        extra: Any? = null
    ) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> {
        val type = viewType<V>()
        sections.addAll(data.map { Section(type, it, extra) })
    }

    inline fun <reified V> addView(
    ) where V : View {
        val type = viewType<V>()
        sections.add(Section(viewType<V>(), null, null))
    }

    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any> addSectionsAndNotify(
        data: Collection<Model>,
        extra: Any? = null
    ) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> {
        addSections<V, Model>(data, extra)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any> addSectionsAndNotifyRange(
        data: Collection<Model>,
        extra: Any? = null
    ) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> {
        addSections<V, Model>(data, extra)
        notifyItemRangeChanged(itemCount - data.size, itemCount)
    }
    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any> addSectionsAndNotifyCompleteRange(
        data: Collection<Model>,
        extra: Any? = null
    ) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> {
        addSections<V, Model>(data, extra)
        notifyItemRangeChanged(itemCount - data.size, itemCount)
    }


    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any?> setSection(
        position: Int,
        data: Model,
        extra: Any? = null
    ) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> {
        sections[position] = Section(viewType<V>(), data, extra)
    }

    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any?> setSectionAndNotify(
        position: Int,
        data: Model,
        extra: Any? = null
    ) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> {
        setSection<V, Model>(position, data, extra)
        notifyItemChanged(position)
    }

    fun updateSection(
        position: Int,
    ) {
        notifyItemChanged(position)
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            notifyItemChanged(position)
        }
    }
    
    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any> addSection(
        data: Model,
        extra: Any? = null
    ) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> {
        sections.add(Section(viewType<V>(), data, extra))
    }

    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any> addSectionAndNotify(
        data: Model,
        extra: Any? = null
    ) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> {
        addSection<V, Model>(data, extra)
        notifyItemInserted(sections.size - 1)
    }

    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any?> createEmptySection(
        data: Model?,
        extra: Any? = null
    ): Section<Model?> where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> =
        Section(viewType<V>(), data, extra)

    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any> createSection(
        data: Model,
        extra: Any? = null
    ): Section<Model> where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> =
        Section(viewType<V>(), data, extra)


    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any> addSection(
        position: Int,
        data: Model,
        extra: Any? = null
    ) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> {
        sections.add(position, Section(viewType<V>(), data, extra))
    }

    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any?> addEmpotySection(
        position: Int,
        data: Model? = null,
        extra: Any? = null
    ) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> {
        val type = viewType<V>()
        if (sections.find { it.type == type } != null) {
            sections.add(position, Section(viewType<V>(), data, extra))
            val index = sections.indexOfLast { it.type == type }
            providers.delete(index)
            sections.removeAt(index)
            notifyItemRangeChanged(index-1,1)
        } else {
            sections.add(position, Section(viewType<V>(), data, extra))
            notifyItemInserted(position)
        }
    }

    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any> addSectionAndNotify(
        position: Int,
        data: Model,
        extra: Any? = null
    ) where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> {
        addSection<V, Model>(position, data, extra)
        notifyItemInserted(position)
    }


    inline fun <reified V, reified Model : Any> createSections(
        data: Collection<Model>,
        extra: Any? = null
    ): List<Section<Model>> where V : View, V : GenericAdapterView<Model> =
        data.map { Section(viewType<V>(), it, extra) }


    fun createSection(
        cls: Class<*>,
        data: Any,
        extra: Any? = null
    ): Section<*> =
        Section(viewType(cls), data, extra)


    fun clearData() {
        sections.clear()
    }

    fun clearDataAndNotify() {
        sections.clear()
        providers.clear()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inline fun <reified V : View> clearViews() {
        val type = viewType<V>()
        sections.removeAll { it.type == type }
    }

    inline fun <reified V : View> findIndexItem(): Int {
        val type = viewType<V>()
        var item = 0
        sections.forEachIndexed { index, section ->
            if (section.type == type) {
                item = index
            }
        }
        return item
    }

    inline fun <reified V : View> findIndexItemNew(): Int? {
        val type = viewType<V>()
        var item: Int? = null
        sections.forEachIndexed { index, section ->
            if (section.type == type) {
                item = index
            }
        }
        return item
    }

    inline fun <reified V : View> clearSectionsWithTypeAndNotify() {
        clearViews<V>()
        notifyItemRemoved(viewType<V>(false))
        providers.delete(viewType<V>(false))
    }

    inline fun <reified T> sectionsWithType(): List<Section<T>> =
        sections.mapIndexed { index, section -> section.index = index; section }
            .filter { it.data is T }.map { it as Section<T> }

}

fun AppGenericAdapter.setSectionsInViewsListAndTryToRecycle(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    lpProvider: (AppGenericAdapter.(Section<*>, Int) -> ViewGroup.LayoutParams)? = null
) {
    for (i in 0 until sections.size) {
        val section = sections[i]
        if (i < parent.childCount) {
            try {
                val child = parent.getChildAt(i) as GenericAdapterView<Any>
                child.onBind(section.data as Any, i, section.extraObject)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                parent.removeAllViews()
                setSectionsInViewsListAndTryToRecycle(parent)
            }
        } else {
            val vh = onCreateViewHolder(parent, section.type)
            if (vh.itemView is GenericAdapterView<*>) {
                (vh.itemView as GenericAdapterView<Any>).onBind(
                    section.data!!,
                    i,
                    section.extraObject
                )
            }
            if (lpProvider != null) {
                vh.itemView.layoutParams = lpProvider(section, i)
            }
            parent.addView(vh.itemView)
        }
    }
    if (parent.childCount - sections.size > 0) {
        parent.removeViews(sections.size, parent.childCount - sections.size)
    }
}
```

This is a Generic adapter class you can use in all project instances of a simple adapter. you just add an item and pass to the generic class to create your list.

**How to User**
First of all, you must add this class to your project.

```
abstract class BaseCustomView<viewDataBinding : ViewDataBinding> @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : RelativeLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    lateinit var binding: viewDataBinding

    init {
        this.inflate(context, attrs)
    }

    @CallSuper
    protected open fun inflate(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?){

        val bindingClass = javaClass.findGenericWithType<viewDataBinding>(ViewDataBinding::class.java)

        if(isInEditMode){
            if(bindingClass != null){
                val resId = bindingClass.layoutId(context)
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resId, this, true)
            }
        } else {
            binding = bindingClass?.getMethod("inflate", LayoutInflater::class.java, ViewGroup::class.java, Boolean::class.java)?.invoke(null, LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true) as viewDataBinding
            binding.setView(this)
        }
    }


}
```

after that, your item (VH), must inheritance this class like this

```
class YourItem @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : BaseCustomView<YouBinding>(context, attrs, defStyleAttr),
    GenericAdapterView<Model> {
    override fun onBind(model: Model, position: Int, extraObject: Any?) {
    }
}
```

and finally, append an item to the adapter

```
private val adapter = AppGenericAdapter().apply {
    provider { context ->
        YourItem (context,)// if you want to pass extra data you can pass data as arg
    }
    provider { context ->
        YourItemButton(context,)// if you want to pass extra data you can pass data as arg
    }
}

binding.recycler.adapter = adapter
adapter.addSectionsAndNotify<YourItem , Model>(data)
// you can check with if the last item add this item
adapter.addSectionsAndNotify<YourItemButton , Model>(data)
```